# An inequality about the CDF of a random variable

Tags: probability

I have to prove that for a random variable  $X\sim N(0,1)$,

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(X>t) \leq \frac{1}{2}\,e^{-\frac{t^2}2}. 
\end{equation*}

I tried using the fact that for $h(t)=e^{\alpha t}$,

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(|X|>t)\leq \frac{E(h(X))}{h(t)} 
\end{equation*}

but didn't manage to advance that much.

Comment: I think this was answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988822/normal-distribution-tail-probability-inequality

Comment: And here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658398/bound-on-the-q-function-related-to-chernoff-bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the density of the standard normal variable we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}[X>t]&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2/2}\,dx=\frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-xt-x^2/2}\,dx\\&\leq&\frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-xt}\,dx=\color{red}{\frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{t\sqrt{2\pi}}},\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence a stronger inequality is true for sure for any $t>\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$. If $t\leq\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$, we just need to exploit:
$$ \frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-xt-x^2/2}\,dx\leq \frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2/2}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{2}} $$
hence we have:

> $$ \forall t>0,\qquad \mathbb{P}[X>t]\leq \frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{\max(2,t\sqrt{2\pi})}.$$

That can also be improved up to:
$$ \forall t>0,\qquad \mathbb{P}[X>t]\leq \frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{\sqrt{4+2\pi t^2}}.$$

Have a look at the Wikipedia page about the [Mills Ratio](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MillsRatio.html) and its continued fraction representation.